# creating a class with class name

Tags: java, class, public

I am a beginner in Java. Could anyone please help me understand the following concept?

What I have done here is I tried to create a class as `Sample`, which I mentioned below, where I am printing `You are in Main Method`

```
class Sample 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("You are in Main Method");
    }

}
```

and saved this java file as **Student.java**.

I didn't get any error in Eclipse.

Now, I had specified a `public` in front of this class as `public class Sample` and I am getting an error.

Could anyone please clarify for me with the right answer, as I am finding this to be difficult to understand?

Comment: you need delete ` symbols

Comment: I think you should do a little reading first about Classes and access level modifiers. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java all classes with scope `public` must be save in file which name is exactly the same like name of this class. So if you have class named `Sample` it has to be saved in file named `Sample.java`. If class is named `Student` then file should be named `Student.java`

One of reason for this is that `packages` named and `class` names can be easly mapped to real system paths.

Comment: dude, could u explain this statement with some more example its not clear "One of reason for this is that packages named and class names can be easly mapped to real system paths"

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the class name is equal to the file name appended with ".java". So if you name your class `Sample` then the file should be named `Sample.java`. This is why you're getting the error because your class name is different to what you have named the file.

For future references, when you're getting a compiler error/run time error, whatever, please ensure that you list the error here. It makes it a lot easier to deal with the problem, and the chances that you will get an answer that actually solves your problem increases.

Answer (score 0):

All public class must be saved with the same name.
So if you have class named Sample it has to be saved in file named Sample.java

If you use a package, you have to save file in this folder.
Example com.example, you have to save Sample.java in a folder  root/com/example.

```
package com.example;

public class Sample{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   // put here your code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Public classes must have their own compilation units (i.e. `.java` files which must match the class name) and are compiled into `ClassName.class` files.

This way the JDK knows where it should generate the output `.class` files and the JVM know where to load the `.class` files from.

An exception to this would be inner/nested classes which do not require a separate file and that get their byte code generated into files like `OuterClassName#InnerClassName.class`. Inner classes are stored in the same `.java` file as the outer class that defines them.

Note:`ClassName`, `OuterClassName` and `InnerClassName` are the names of the classes defined by you.

Answer (score 0):

first u read visibility of modifies i think u r well understanding ur problem

Access Modifiers

```
Same Class  Same Package    Subclass    Other packages
```

public  Y   Y   Y   Y
protected   Y   Y   Y   N
no access modifier  Y   Y   N             N
private     Y   N   N   N

Comment: could you explain in detail how this Access Modifiers is linked with my question above, i couldn't able to understand the solution for my above question if u could explain in detail i will be more thankful, thanks in advance